# Getting Unexpected User Param and Can't access Password Param in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, reactjs, authentication

I started setting up a user authentication system in Rails with React and there are two weird things happening:

1) My POST request is including a `user` param that I'm pretty sure I didn't configure myself (I was following along with a Rails guideline book). This `user` param has a duplication of all of my other params, as shown:

```
Started POST "/api/user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-29 21:54:42 -0800
Processing by Api::UserController#create as JSON
   Parameters: {"email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
       "first_name"=>"test", "last_name"=>"test", "groupname"=>"test", 
       "admin"=>"true", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", 
       "first_name"=>"test", "last_name"=>"test", "groupname"=>"test", "admin"=>"true"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
No template found for Api::UserController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 39ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

2) If you didn't notice already, my `password` param is the only one that isn't included in my `user` param (probably because of me calling `has_secure_password` in my `users` model?), and I can't figure out how to add it to my `private` variable.

I'm simply trying to write my new user's information into my Postgres database using `Users.new()`. Here is what I'm working with:

**index.js**

```
class Signup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this. state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      groupname: '',
      admin: false
    }

   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
   this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }


 handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  }


 handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post('/api/user', {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      first_name: this.state.first_name,
      last_name: this.state.last_name,
      groupname: this.state.groupname,
      admin: this.state.admin
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
    })
 }



render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Sign Up!</h3>



        <section>
          <div>
                <div className='box'>
                  <p className="subtitle has-text-grey">Create Account</p>
                  <hr />

                  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                    <div className="field">
                      <div className="control">
                        <label>E-mail

                          <input name="email" type="text" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange} defaultValue={this.state.email}></input>

                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div className="field">
                      <div className="control">
                        <label>Password

                          <input name="password" type="password" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange} defaultValue={this.state.password}></input>

                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="field">
                      <div className="control">

                        <label >First Name

                          <input type="text" className="form-control" name="first_name" onChange={this.handleChange} defaultValue={this.state.first_name}></input>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="field">
                      <div className="control">
                        <label>Last Name
                          <input type="text" className="form-control" name="last_name" onChange={this.handleChange} defaultValue={this.state.last_name}></input>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="field">
                      <div className="control">
                        <label>Group


                          <input name="groupname" type="text" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange} defaultValue={this.state.groupname}></input>

                          <hr />

                          <span className='adminLabel' style={styles.adminLabelStyle}>Are you registerting as an admin?</span> <span>     </span>



                          <input type="checkbox" id="groupadmin" name="admin" onChange={this.handleChange} value='true'></input>

                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="field is-grouped">
                      <div className="control">
                          <input type="submit" value='Submit' className="button is-normal is-info"></input>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>

                  <hr />

                  <form >
                    <div className="feild">
                      <div className="control">
                        <div>Already a Member?
                          <input type="submit" value='Login' className="" onClick={ this.props.action }></input>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
            </div>
          </div>

        </section>


      </div>
    )
  }
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= react_component('Index') %>
```

**app/controllers/api/user_controller.rb**

```
class Api::UserController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

    def create
        user_params[:password] = params[:password]
        puts user_params
        @user = Users.new(user_params)
    end


    private
        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :groupname, :admin)
        end


end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 51 }
    validates :groupname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 51 }
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
    has_secure_password
end
```

**db schema**

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.integer "groupid"
    t.string "groupname"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "admin"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end
```

All in all my actual questions are:
WHY am I getting a separate `users` param, WHY doesn't it include my password, and WHY can't I add the password to my `user_params`??

Comment: Can you show the browser's log of request?

Comment: Can you add the form code ..?

Comment: @user3309314 do you mean the log in my terminal when I submit the post request? If so it I've updated the question to reflect the entire log

Comment: @BalaKarthik by form code do you mean in the view? If so I currently have my React rendering on one `index.html.erb` page but I can include it if you think it will help

Comment: Do you have specific gems/library on frontend that used for authentication?

Comment: @Tai the only package im using for this is bcrypt...

Comment: @Naji I mean Chrome's dev console or something like this.

Comment: http://adamalbrecht.com/2015/07/20/authentication-using-json-web-tokens-using-rails-and-react/

Comment: sorry, but it looks like either you have cache issue (js in browser?) or not posting some important part. Can you ensure that app is restarted and browser cache is cleared? Also can you show all the code (ex on github)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails has a config option `wrap_parameters` which is enabled by default. This will detect if you haven't provided a root element (`:user` in this instance), and will duplicate the keys into a root element for you. That is what is causing your first issue.

Password isn't included in the wrapped parameters because it isn't a defined attribute on your model. Only the keys returned in the class method `attribute_names` are wrapped. You can get explicitly include additional keys with the following method in your controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    wrap_parameters :user, include: [:password]
end
```

Alternatively you could just nest the parameters you send to your rails controller under the `user` key, and ignore `wrap_parameters` entirely.

```
axios.post('/api/user', {
    user: {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password,
        first_name: this.state.first_name,
        last_name: this.state.last_name,
        groupname: this.state.groupname,
        admin: this.state.admin
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the info on `wrap_parameters`! I ended up doing exactly what you said, nesting the parameters under a `user` key. I'm curious though, when you say that `password` isn't a defined attribute in my model, where are you referring? In my `UsersController` I never defined any attributes in my model, so why is it that everything else is getting defined by default EXCEPT for password?

Comment: ActiveRecord will define your table columns as attributes automatically, but password is just a setter method defined by has_secure_password. password_digest on the other hand might be included since it's a column, but I haven't tested that.